# Is there a geometric progression containing 2, 3 and 5

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing

I am trying to find a geometric progression containing 2, 3 and 5 (the terms do not have to be consecutive). If there is no such progression, is it possible to prove this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $$ar^n=2, ar^{n+x}=3, ar^{n+y}=5$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume that $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a geometric progression, $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=r$, and
$$ a_m = 2,\qquad a_{m+i}=3,\qquad a_{m+j}=5. $$ 
That implies $\frac{5}{2}=r^j$ and $\frac{3}{2}=r^{i}$, hence:
$$ \left(\frac{5}{2}\right)^i\cdot\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{j} = 1 $$
but that is equivalent to:
$$ 2^{j-i} 5^i = 3^{j} $$
that contradicts the unique factorization theorem.