# Is there a geometric sequence that contains each of the numbers 1, 2 and 3?

Tags: geometric-series

I recently got the question:

> Is there a geometric sequence that contains each of the numbers 1, 2 and 3?

I have tried my best to make a start with the $x_n=ar^{(n-1)}$ theorem but I'm still puzzled!

On stack exchange I have also seen [**this very similar question**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1419698/is-there-a-geometric-progression-containing-2-3-and-5) but I don't see how it really works...

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: What part of that answer do you not see? This question can be solved almost identically to that one.

Comment: @RushabhMehta I don't know how the equation works and what numbers need to be plugged in where

Comment: It's not an equation. Read it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a geometric progression, $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=r$, and
$$ a_m = 1,\qquad a_{m+i}=2,\qquad a_{m+j}=3. $$
That implies $3=r^j$ and $2=r^{i}$, hence:
$$ 3^i = r^{ij}$$
$$ 2^j = r^{ij}$$
but that is equivalent to:
$$ 3^i = 2^j  $$
but that is only possible when $i=j=0$ but it is not possible because if  $i=j=0$ then both $ a_{m+i}=2,a_{m+j}=3 $ become $a_m$ but $a_m$ cannot be 1, 2 and 3 simultaneously